# How to remove the white space

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the space between the pictures:

[image: This here]

```
        <div style="width: 70.9%; height: 139px; border: 2px solid black; white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: none;">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZR8D_OugGiw"><img src="Grafiken/Last1.png" width="250px" height="140px"/></a>
    <img src="Grafiken/Last2.png" width="250px" height="140px"/>
    <img src="Grafiken/Last3.png" width="250px" height="140px"/>
    <img src="Grafiken/Last4.png" width="250px" height="140px"/>
    <img src="Grafiken/Last5.png" width="250px" height="140px"/>
    <img src="Grafiken/Last1.png" width="250px" height="140px"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make them `display: block` in your CSS.